# (Web)app to search metabolic/signalling pathways

Tags: biochemistry, bioinformatics, physiology

I'm looking for an application where you can find pathways by selecting a chemical occurring in it.

So, for example,
selecting 6-phosphogluconolactone brings up the pentose phosphate pathway or any other where it occurs as an intermediate or product.

Same could be possible for endocrine or any other signalling. The target organism is human.

Is there anything like this in existence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KEGG  http://www.genome.jp/kegg/kegg2.html

GLAMM http://glamm.lbl.gov/

I had to truncate to gluconolactone to make the search work in both cases.

Comment: Thanks, the first seems better though less fancy.

Comment: Many would agree with you; KEGG may be the best established pathway database of all.

Comment: KEGG has also a [very nice API](http://www.kegg.jp/kegg/rest/), if you plan some automatable tasks.